# How to insert an inline SVG image within another SVG

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have some SVG code created with a vector program that should be included via javascript into other SVG files. I do want to have the code in the javascript file itself. So is there anything in the SVG DOM API where i can give directly SVG code instead of using methods like "createElementNS"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [DomParser API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/DOMParser) will allow you to turn an XML string into objects. E.g.

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(stringContainingXMLSource, "image/svg+xml");
```

Then you can use doc.documentElement to get the root element of the parsed data. If you want to insert this into your document as a child of an existing element then

```
element.appendChild(document.importNode(doc.documentElement, true));
```

should do the trick.

Note that the root element of stringContainingXMLSource will need an SVG xmlns attribute e.g. `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`